# How do I use `sed` to strip the version information of a list of packages?

Tags: command-line

The result for example of a search is a list > /tmp/lista.txt:

```
vlc-2.2.1-195.1.x86_64
pidgin-2.10.11-4.3.x86_64
qmmp-1.0.5-78.1.x86_64
spotify-client-0.9.17.8.gd06432d.31-1.x86_64
```

I'm  using:

```
cat /tmp/lista.txt | sed 's/[^a-z]*//g'
```

But I want the result to be:

```
vlc 
pidgin
qmmp
spotify-client
```

Answer (score 3):

I posit that this is not possible to do in a practical way. Not with your list.

The problem of slicing off the numbers, or just selecting the text, or whatever version of kink you want to get inolved with, hyphens and numbers are perfectly valid characters in package *names*. Run `dpkg -l | awk '$2~/-[0-9]/'`. I see ~622 such packages on my 14.04 desktop. And no, these aren't the whole version numbers.

Let's look at some `openjdk` packages:

```
openjdk-6-jre:amd64             6b37-1.13.9-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64    6b37-1.13.9-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-6-jre-lib               6b37-1.13.9-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jdk:amd64             7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jre:amd64             7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64    7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jre-lib               7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

I assume that if these are in your list they would display as:

```
openjdk-6-jre:amd64-6b37-1.13.9-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64-6b37-1.13.9-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-6-jre-lib-6b37-1.13.9-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jdk:amd64-7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jre:amd64-7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64-7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
openjdk-7-jre-lib-7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

So perhaps now you can see why these are hard to extract. If you rip off anything past a number, you end up not being able to distinguish several sorts of package.

My advice is to get a better list with a proper delimiter that aren't allowed in package names. Spaces, commas, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could match a hyphen followed by a digit, and replace that and everything thereafter

```
$ sed 's/-[0-9].*//' lista.txt 
vlc
pidgin
qmmp
spotify-client
```

Comment: Bit risky isn't it? Packages can contain both hyphens and numbers, without actually being the package version. `dpkg -l | awk '$2~/-[0-9]/'` for some examples that are matched by your regex (and would break if in the list).

Comment: @Oli all the OP says is it's "a search": I based my suggestion on the info provided

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver that's what i was looking forward. The packages were just an example because they have a lot of stuff mix together. And if you search a package usually you use a more simple expression like "vlc".

Comment: @p.Trinx do bear in mind Oli's comment (and answer) though - else you may get unexpected results